# HTMLAgilityPack xpath required

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have the following HTML

```
<td>
 <input type="button" />
</td>
<td>
 <a href="somelink">blah blah shared</a>
 <a href="somelink"></a>
 <a href="somelink">blah blah post</a>
</td>
<td>
 <a href="somelink">blah blah </a>
 <a href="somelink">some text</a>
 <a href="somelink">more text</a>
</td>
```

Now.. I need the xpath to return the 'td' element that contains 'a' tags that contains the words 'post' and 'shared'

I think it has something like
//tr[td[1][. = 'post']]

Comment: What have you tried? What does or doesn't the xpath you show do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that tag by using the following code, no matter at which position or node the word "post" or "shared" come, it will get you that node.

```
IEnumerable<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode> nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td/a[@href]")
                                                 .Where(x => x.InnerText.Contains("post") || x.InnerText.Contains("shared"));
```

It is tested code, it works with the given html.

Comment: Had to make some changes for the actual HTML I have, but this put me on the right path

Answer (score 0):

You can make the selection entirely within a single XPath:

```
//td[contains(a,'shared') and contains(a,'post')]
```

will select all `td` elements with an `a` child that contains `"shared"` *and* an `a` child that contains `"post"`.  Note that the targeted strings may appear in the same or in different `a` elements.